# X server doesn't start after upgrading vbox lubuntu 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, virtualbox, lubuntu, xorg

I upgraded a virtualbox from lubuntu 17.10 to 18.04. On reboot, X doesn't start, though I can enter the console via -F1. Attempting to restart doesn't result in anything obviously interesting in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or `~/.xsession-errors`, <s>which I have included below.</s>There is console message when I run `systemctl restart display-manager`, though, `[drm:vbox_bo_unpin [vboxvideo]]

**EDIT**: I removed the diagnostic output; please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be that I was running 16.04 on the host, which was getting me virtualbox-5.1. Upgrading to 5.2 on the host fixed my problem.